# How can retrieve values in update mode using smarty (PHP)?

Tags: php, smarty

I want to make email template management.I have a column `additional_data` where I'm inserting two input fields values (Subject and Body.)

Subject value contain simple text and body value contain HTML and other templates related materials.

### My PHP Code

```
$additional_data = array();

    // getting data again for update to fill up form
    $editdata = ($id && $display == 'Update') ? $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM `{$db_table}` WHERE `nli_id`='$id'") : FALSE;

if(!is_array($editdata['additional_data']) && count($editdata['additional_data']))
    $additional_data = json_decode($editdata['additional_data'], TRUE);
    p($additional_data, 'Additional Data');

        // setting template vars
    if(count($additional_data))
    {
        foreach($additional_data as $key => $value)
        {
            $tmpl->setvar($key, $value);
        } // foreach ends
           unset($key);
           unset($value);
    } // if ends
```

### HTML Code

```
<input type="text" class="span6" autocomplete="off" name="subject" id="subject" value="{var name='additional_data'}">

<textarea name="body" class="span6 autogrow">{var name='additional_data'}</textarea>
```

So let me know where I am wrong or is there any other way to solve the problem.

Comment: what's the problem? or is this for code review?

Comment: on update (edit) mode inserted value not retrieving in input fields.

Comment: Is this code really Smarty? I don't know tag `var` neither in Smarty3 nor in Smarty2. Instead of `{var name='additional_data'}` I use always {$additional_data}. Is it some extension or your mod? We don't know what is being returned in `$editdata`. You should var_dump this value before first `if` and before second `if` to make sure it contains value you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this "smarty" looks very strange. I would say it's Vlib:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VlibTemplate

But anyway, in you PHP code you are going trough $additional_data array and creating variables from elements of that array. Element key is name of new template variable and element value is tmpl. variable value.
So, in your template code "additional_data" does not exist. Print out that $additional_data array from your PHP code to see what elements are you really passing to template engine.